# Checking and Inserting Data in MySQL Using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Hi I have this code which is supposed to check if a row exists in a MySQL table and insert data if it doesn't. It doesn't work and I'm pretty sure it's a mess because I'm new to MySQL.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<?php
$mysqlhost="host";
$mysqldatabase="databasename";
$mysqlusername="username";
$mysqlpassword="password";
$connect=mysqli_connect("$mysqlhost","$mysqlusername","$mysqlpassword","$mysqldatabase");

$username=$_POST['username'];
$password=$_POST['Password'];
$email=$_POST['Email'];
$gender=$_POST['Gender'];
$tutorgroup=$_POST['tutorgroup'];
$queryinstruction="SELECT FROM Users (Username, Password, Email) WHERE Username=$username";
$result=mysqli_query($connect,$queryinstruction);
$nouser=mysql_num_rows($result);
if($nouser<1){
 $newaccount="INSERT INTO Users (Username,Password,Gender,Email,Tutor Group)
 VALUES($username,$password,$email,$gender,$tutorgroup)";
 }
 else{
  echo "An account with that username already exists!";
  
  }
 
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Can you tell me where I got stuff wrong? I'm basically searching the table for a matching username then using mysql_num_rows() to return the number of rows and see if its below 1. Thanks in advance.

Comment: One big problem is your SQL injection vulnerabilities. Switch to parameter binding as your first priority - there is no point fixing this and leaving it hackable. Your other problem is you are not checking for success after each call - after you connect, read the `$connect` variable and test it for success (look at the manual to see what values to check for). Ditto for the query and result count calls.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I suggest you start using PDO rather than the standard Mysql functions. Your code has lots of security issues and using PDO will solve them before you begin.

With your query the username is a string so should have quotes around it:

WHERE Username='$username'"

It's also a good idea when debugging to use the following line for the query execution:

$result=mysqli_query($connect,$queryinstruction) or die(mysql_error());

This will tell you whatever the error is in your query. Take the die() out of production code though.